# What is IdThreadComponent Loop property?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy

I expected that by using `Loop` property I can define if `OnRun` event method is repeatedly executed, but regardless, it is always repeating until I call method `Terminate`. Am I missing the point of this property or there is a bug in the IdThreadComponent component?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Provide us a MVCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `TIdThreadComponent` runs a `TIdThread`, which actually has 2 loops in its `Execute()` method:

- An outer loop is a usual `while not Terminated` loop.
- Inside of that loop, it first checks if the `Stop()` method has been called to suspend the thread, and then (after waking up if stopped) it checks `Loop` to determine whether the `Run()` method should be called one time or in a loop.

So, the `Loop` property does not really have much effect in `TIdThreadComponent`, because of the outer `while not Terminated` loop.  All it really does is helps you control how often the thread checks its `Stopped` property to know when go to sleep, if ever.

The `Loop` logic is primarily meant for use by `TIdTCPServer` instead, to control whether its `OnExecute` event is fired one time or repeatedly for each accepted client connection.

Comment: So, I pretty much misunderstood the property's meaning. Thanks!

Comment: Not your fault.  It is not well-documented behavior